# Explaining why solutions to $6x-5y=1$ exist, $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Its obvious that the equation  $$6x-5y=1$$  where $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$
 has solutions, but I was curious as to what the reason. I thought the reason had the following line of reasoning:

$$6x-5y \equiv 0-5 \equiv -5 \equiv 1\bmod6$$

and since $\mathrm{LHS}\equiv\mathrm{RHS}\bmod6$ solutions to the equation must exist.

Is this logic flawed?

Comment: You have shown there is a solution modulo $6$. We need to show there are integer solutions. That, too, is easy since the numbers are small.

Comment: I was just wondering if an equation must have solutions if they are equivalent when working in some $moda$

Comment: Consider the equation $6x-2y=1$. There is a solution modulo $3$, but no integer solution.

Comment: If there is **no** solution mod $m$ for some $m$, **then** there is no integer solution. That can be very useful.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense

Answer (score 2):

This equation has integer solutions since 6 and 5 are relatively prime. Do a quick search on the "extended Euclidean algorithm".

Comment: I know that they do, x and y can be 1 as an example, I was just wondering why.

Answer (score 1):

$ax + by = 0$ is called Homogeneous Diophantine Equations. More in general $ax + by = c$ is called Diophantine Equation, and it has solutions if and only if $GCD(a,b) | c$. Now, suppose you've found 2 solutions of the Non-Homogeneous Equation, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, then every couple $(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$ satisfies the Homogeneous Equation. As a consequence, in order to find all the solutions of the Non-Homogeneous Equation you need only 1 solution of the Non-Homogeneous Equation and all the solutions of the Homogeneous Equation.
In this case $ c = 1$, so for the $Bezout$ $Theorem$ it is only needed that $GCD(a,b) = 1$ ($a$ and $b$ are coprimes, and you can find infinite solutions (see $Euclidean$ $Algorithm$ $Method$ on how to find them) !

Comment: say instead a and b are not integer but are are expressions; i.e $(2k+3)x-(2k)y=1$ by finding one pair of solutions $(x,y)$ could you apply the Bezout Theorem and assert that there are an infinite number of solutions $(x,y)$

Comment: Yes of course there are infinite solutions ( unless $GCD(a,b) \ne 1$ ). In fact by substituting any integer you find a Non-Homogeneous Equation where $c = 1$, (so it's called $Linear Equation$, and you can apply $Bezout$ $Theorem$...but finding the solutions of term of $k$ , for example, it's another story...

Answer (score 0):

Bézout's Identity states that there are integers such that $ax + by = d$, where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, that means $d=1$ and integer solutions exist.